# getting an error while connecting to sql server 2008 enterprise edition

Tags: java, sql-server-2008

i am trying to connect with sql server 2008 using java connection string but i am getting following error

jdbc:sqlserver://127.0.0.1:1434;DatabaseNameconnect?autoReconnect=true
com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: The server version is not supported. The target server must be SQL Server 2000 or later.
com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: The server version is not supported. The target server must be SQL Server 2000 or later.
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException.makeFromDriverError(Unknown Source)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.DBComms.Prelogin(Unknown Source)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.DBComms.(Unknown Source)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.connect(Unknown Source)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver.connect(Unknown Source)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:582)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:185)
    at com.dnb.discovery.connection.ConnectionBean.makeMsSqlConnection(ConnectionBean.java:56)
    at com.dnb.discovery.factory.MssqlDAOFactory.(MssqlDAOFactory.java:18)
    at com.dnb.discovery.dao.mssqldao.MssqlCompanyDAO.(MssqlCompanyDAO.java:8)
    at com.dnb.discovery.relevance.Relevance.(Relevance.java:26)
    at com.dnb.discovery.dao.SolrDAO.readDataFromSolr(SolrDAO.java:189)
    at com.dnb.discovery.searchservice.SearchService.buyerTextSearchAnonymous(SearchService.java:124)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.api.server.InstanceResolver$1.invoke(InstanceResolver.java:210)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.server.InvokerTube$2.invoke(InvokerTube.java:132)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.server.sei.EndpointMethodHandler.invoke(EndpointMethodHandler.java:241)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.server.sei.SEIInvokerTube.processRequest(SEIInvokerTube.java:74)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.api.pipe.Fiber.__doRun(Fiber.java:581)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.api.pipe.Fiber._doRun(Fiber.java:540)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.api.pipe.Fiber.doRun(Fiber.java:525)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.api.pipe.Fiber.runSync(Fiber.java:422)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.server.WSEndpointImpl$2.process(WSEndpointImpl.java:226)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.transport.http.HttpAdapter$HttpToolkit.handle(HttpAdapter.java:375)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.transport.http.HttpAdapter.handle(HttpAdapter.java:175)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.transport.http.server.WSHttpHandler.handleExchange(WSHttpHandler.java:100)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.transport.http.server.WSHttpHandler.handle(WSHttpHandler.java:77)
    at com.sun.net.httpserver.Filter$Chain.doFilter(Filter.java:65)
    at sun.net.httpserver.AuthFilter.doFilter(AuthFilter.java:65)
    at com.sun.net.httpserver.Filter$Chain.doFilter(Filter.java:68)
    at sun.net.httpserver.ServerImpl$Exchange$LinkHandler.handle(ServerImpl.java:555)
    at com.sun.net.httpserver.Filter$Chain.doFilter(Filter.java:65)
    at sun.net.httpserver.ServerImpl$Exchange.run(ServerImpl.java:527)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:619)

i am using following jar for connection

sqljdbc-2005-1.0.jar

please help

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're using a SQL Server 2005 JDBC driver, but talking to SQL Server 2008. While I would have *expected* that to work, I suspect the best approach would probably be to update your JDBC driver:

- [Download page for the latest MS JDBC driver](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?displaylang=en&id=11774)